# Can't override VideoWidget paintEvent() in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt4, overriding, repaint, qpainter

I'm trying to draw some shapes over a VideoWidget from the Phonon library, but I can't override the paintEvent() method.

If I try to implement the method like this:

```
void Phonon::VideoWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red,3));
    qDebug()<< "repintando";
    painter.drawEllipse(500,500,100,100);
}
```

I get this error: no ‘void Phonon::VideoWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)’ member function declared in class ‘Phonon::VideoWidget’

So I decided to create a myVideoWidget header with the protected method paintEvent and implemented it in mainwindow.cpp like this:

```
void myVideoWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red,3));
    qDebug()<< "repintando";
    painter.drawEllipse(500,500,100,100);
}
```

And the program runs but it doesn't draw anything or displays the "repintando" message.

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you see something when you resize or change the widget state (minimize/maximize)? Try calling the update() method of your myVideoWidget class. Does that do anything?

Comment: I tried what you say but I can't see anything and also can't see the message I send to qDebug(), that means the method is not being executed.
Thank you the same!

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, You've delivered your own class, that inherits Phonon::VideoWidget and you set it as your video widget for your player? If yes, than you need to modify your paintEvent to something like this:

```
void myVideoWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    Phonon::VideoWidget::paintEvent(event); // perform paint event from inherited class
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red,3));
    qDebug()<< "repintando";
    painter.drawEllipse(500,500,100,100);
}
```

BUT! I'm not sure if VideoWidget uses paintEvent to render video frames. It is possible That you will have to invoke your paintEvent manualy. Try using repaint instead of update maybe.

Comment: I think that's a good idea, but it doesn't work. That would be useful if I could only see the ellipse and not the video. The problem is that I'm not overriding the method well. There's something I'm doing wrong that makes the paintEvent not being executed, but don't know what.
Maybe the parameters are not ok so the signature doesn't match with the one from VideoWidget but I've already checked it.

Thank you the same!

Comment: Well as I said VideoWidget may not use paintEvent to render anything. You could add translucent widget on VideoWidget and paint on that widget instead